# Azure Automation - Cannot find the 'Connect-AzAccount'

Tags: azure-automation

I'm taking my first steps into Azure Automation.
For start I'm trying to use the Stop / Start all or only tagged Azure VMs in parallel runbook from the Gallery. When I tried to launch it for the first time I got an error:

*Cannot find the 'Connect-AzAccount' command. If this command is defined as a workflow, ensure it is defined before the workflow that calls it. If it is a command intended to run directly within Windows PowerShell (or is not available on this system), place it in an InlineScript: 'InlineScript { Connect-AzAccount }'*

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing the problem?  As far as I understand the AZ module is the newest one so I find it odd that the command was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. I did not expect you need to explicitly import the modules that you are using in the workflow.

Regards,

Wojciech